# Printing HTML data with Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am doing a course in Python 2.7, but at the same time, I want to be able to do everything in Python 3.

Code in Python 2.7:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print data

mysock.close()
```

Yields properly formatted data, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Code in Python 3:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send(('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n').encode())

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
    print(data);

mysock.close()
```

And it yields:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\r\nContent-Length: 2788\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n
```

As you can see, it adds a "b" character, and ignores \r \n. The formatting is way off.
Where did the 'b' come from? How can I make python format it properly?
I have tried converting it to a string, prior to printing but it didn't help.

Comment: That's an interesting way to fetch HTML... Have you found the `requests` library yet?

Comment: @Marki, so basically you're sending and receiving byte in Python3 (properly). So what you need to do is to decode it before print. ie. `print(data.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Thank you both for that. I haven't found the requests library yet. I was however interested in urllib library. I will read about them tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has a `b''` because what is returned by `mysock.recv` is of type `bytes`. You should decode your byte string to a unicode one with `decode`:

```
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Remember, Python 2 and 3 differ regarding strings as specified in [`PEP 3137`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/). Python 3 offers a clear separation between text and binary data, Python 2 doesn't.

The issue here is that when `print` receives your bytes object, it'll call `str` on it which will simply build a string out of it as it knows best; i.e escape backslashes and retain the rest:

```
>>> str(b"hello\nworld")
"b'hello\\nworld'"
```

Then `print` will just take that and print it out.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question :-)